# dynamic sql in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic SQL stored procedure returning multiple number of columns for different items.

For example, item1 - 5 columns, item2 - 4 columns

I am thinking of building SSRS reports using that stored procedure hoping to get multiple results.

For example, when click 'item1', it gives you that 5 columns sp can return whist click 'item2', it gives you that 4 columns sp can return

Can SSRS do this? When I use SP as a source for SSRS, it seems that the output is NOT dynamic as it only returns 'item1'

thanks

r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RS will read column metadata from the first result set of the query.

So I suggest you can add a table variable (fixed columns to support all your dynamic results) into your stored procedure, insert the dynamic query result into the table variable, and then select the result from the table variable.

Comment: in my case, I need at least 5 column to fit both item1 and item2 is it correct? then dynamically display item1 or item2 ?

Comment: Yes, in the stored procedure create a table variable to have item1/item2 data inserted, and then at the end of the stored procedure select all columns from the table variable. In your report create a tablix to hold all columns from the stored procedure, and use expression to hide/show columns, something like "IIF(ISNOTHING(Col), true, false)"

Comment: yeah mate, all solved, what I did is to create a 'big table' in SSRS and manually create fields sp potentially returns and only display the columns based on the sp outputs

Answer (score 0):

what I did is to create a 'big table' in SSRS and manually create fields sp potentially returns and only display the columns based on the sp outputs by using 'viability' option

the only issue is that you need to manually configure each column to indicate under what circumstance it is supposed to appear